# How does Facebook Login ensure that your web application can only be used from your URL?

Tags: javascript, facebook, oauth

When you're integrating with Facebook Login with a web application, you specify the web application's URL in the application settings on Facebook. Attempts to use that app's ID on a page not loaded from that URL gives an appropriate error: "Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration."

How are they doing that without making defeating it trivial? If the app is authorized on `http://example-a.com`, how do they prevent access if I copy the app ID and try to use it from `http://example-b.com`? I'm trying to understand how they do it because I need to do a similar lock-down-by-originating-URL in some work I'm doing.

I have a strong sense of missing the obvious here.

I know they're using an authorization/authentication flow "[based on](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/)" the [OAuth 2.0 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.1) (and that basic flow [isn't exactly complicated](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.2)), but I'm having trouble figuring out at which stage(s) in that flow they validate the originating page's URL and how they're sending that URL to their service while ensuring it hasn't been tampered with / spoofed.

Things I (think I've) eliminated:

1. Although I see them passing around the originating domain (in query strings and such), they can't be relying on just that, it would be trivial to modify the calling code to "adjust" that. I expect that's *part* of the solution, but only part of it.
2. They can't be using the `Referer` (sic) header, as that's trivial to spoof.
3. They can't be using (only) code running within the originating page, as that can be modified.
4. They can't be relying just on `postMessage`, because Facebook Login works on IE8/9 and it's a pop-up window (not just a frame); `postMessage` in IE8/9 [only works within frames](http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging), not separate tabs/windows.

Answer (score 1):

As I was writing my fourth bullet point in the question, I realized what they could be doing (and checking up taught me a very useful few things about `postMessage`).

I think they're doing it roughly like this:

- Facebook code loaded into the originating page (which could, of course, be hacked — but that's handled in a moment) adds an `iframe` loaded from `mumble.facebook.com` to the originating page; the `iframe` contains the Login button.
- The Facebook code on the originating page uses `postMessage` to talk to that `iframe`.
- Code in the `iframe` — which the originating site can't reasonably hack, as it's loaded from `mumble.facebook.com` — uses the `origin` property of the event object it receives with the `postMessage` messages from the originating page; that's how it has a reliable version of the originating origin. That can't be spoofed (barring browser bugs).
- The Login button in the `iframe` opens a popup (loaded from `mumble.facebook.com`), which uses `opener` (but not `postMessage`) to talk to the `iframe` (since the `iframe` and popup are loaded from the same origin, they can do that — and they have to rather than `postMessage`, because of the IE8/9 problem).
- Interaction is then:

  ```
  +------------------+    +--------+    +-------+
  | Originating page |<-->| iframe |<-->| popup |<------+
  +------------------+    +--------+    +-------+       |
                               ^                        v
                               |                   +---------------------+
                               +------------------>| mumble.facebook.com |
                                                   +---------------------+
  ```

Basically, the `iframe` is the proxy between the originating page and the popup (and Facebook in general), and it's at that stage (the communication between the originating page and the `iframe`) that Facebook gets a reliable version of the originating page's origin.

I believe they pass the originating origin to the `iframe` as a query parameter as an added measure; the `iframe` probably uses that for any messages it posts back to the originating page, and so if the query parameter was hacked, those messages never get received by the originating page and nothing works. Or they just compare them.

Since `event.origin` can't be spoofed (barring browser bugs), and the code and markup and such of the `iframe` and popup come from `mumble.facebook.com`, it's reasonably secure and reliable ("reasonably" within the realm of web browsers).

Answer (score 0):

Nice Ascii graphics :-)

I think the answer is much simpler and it applies to all OAuth2 based systems. The app requesting the authorization sends a `redirect_uri` parameter that has to match whatever you registered in the Authorization Server (FB in this case). If what you send doesn't match the registered value, it is rejected. I don't believe they check the referrer or anything else. If the query param matches, the Authorization Server sends user back to the `redirect_uri` with a `code` (and the OAuth2 flow proceeds: get token with the code, etc).

> Apps are supposed to also send a `state` parameter that is preserved throughout the transaction and needs to be checked upon return.

Comment: Yes, but the crux of the matter is how they get a reliable value to send. If it were just code running on the originating page, the value could be spoofed. So that's why I was looking for how that's locked down, and found `event.origin`.